# CKEditor: Paste into editable field in widget

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have a CKEditor widget resembling a tab-module.
As editables I have defined a `span.title` and `div.content`.

When I am in editing mode inside a `span.title` and then paste something using CTRL+V, the span gets broken and I have two spans. As if it gets divided on whatever position I paste.

When I am in editing mode inside a `div.content` and then paste something using CTRL+V, the contents of the clipboard are correctly inserted into that div.

Is it because span is an inline-element and div is a block-element and CKEditor doesnt allow pasting into inline-elements?
Can I somehow change this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

CKEditor allows pasting of block and inline elements (keep in mind that [content filtering (ACF)](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_acf) can be used which also affects pasting) so it is probably not the issue in this case.

I would also make sure that the content which you are trying to paste does not contain any HTML which may cause the behavior you described.

If you could provide widget HTML/template or code which you are using I will be glad to investigate this issue in more depth.

Comment: Let's say I have an editable with id "editable-1" which is a <span>.
Within CKEdit I click into the editable and paste plain text via CTRL+V and voilà, the editable is broken. 
Now, each time I click "show source", a new editable appears...

Comment: Is it possible that you provide your widget HTML so I can test it?

Comment: are you out of ideas?

Comment: It seems I missed your comment with the link, sorry. And now it looks like the link has expired...

Comment: I have a link to another fiddle that shows a similar effect: http://jsfiddle.net/dbz3gqLe/
It guess this is a more commong CKEditor problem since you can't even tripple-click into editables and so on..

Comment: I believe it may be a bug. You can report it in CKEditor bug tracker (http://dev.ckeditor.com/), but I believe there is something similar already reported - http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/12583 (I added the code from jsfiddle you provided there). And when it comes to your initial issue you were asking about, I still haven't seen the code to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when trying to have a `<cite>` element as an editable. Trick was to tweak the `CKEDITOR.dtd` properties.

```js
// This prevents the pasting from splitting parent element.
delete CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty.cite;
// This tells the editor to allow editing in this element.
CKEDITOR.dtd.$editable.cite = 1;
```

I imagine this would affect the behavior of all `<cite>` elements in any editor currently loaded. Not ideal in all cases for most elements, but for our requirements for a blockquote/pullquote widget, the `<cite>` element is only allowed inside our `<blockquote>` elements in any editor.